# Extract terminology from sentences quickly

Tags: python, mongodb, nlp, text-mining

I am working in Text Mining and my work is focused on biomedical entities (genes, proteins, drugs and diseases). I would like to share with you some questions.

Now, my goal is to find biomedical entities in biomedical text (from Medline) and through of dictionaries of terms, I can identify each entity found with its unique identifier.

To store text, dicitionaries and results, I am using MongoDB (a nonSQL database). Each abstract is splitted in sentences, and each sentence is store in a new record (with list of tokens, chunks and Part-of-Speech tags). To find entities, I get all senteces and for each one I create a regular expresion for each term in the dictionary (in Python):

```
for term in dicitonary:
     matches = re.finditer(r'(' + term + ')', sentence)
     for m in matches:
          ini = m.start()
          end = m.end()
          result.append(ini, end, dictionary.get_identification[term])
```

But it is really slow, I have several subsets of 150,000 abstracts (>1,000,000 of sentences).

For me, it is really interesting soft-matching to extract more entities where their terminology is not exactly in my dictionary, but it can increase my running time.

I think that my problem is to do a lot of regular expressions (I have dictionary with 300,000 entries) for each sentence, because I have to find the terms in sentence. Without Machine Learning algorithm, how could you resolve this problem? And with ML algorithms? Now, I am flexible to change my programming language, databases...

Thank you very much!!!

Regards,

àlex.

Comment: Something to consider: There's already some NL processing available for python: [NLTK 2.0](http://nltk.org/). There was even a talk at PyCon/India about [textmining MedLine](http://in.pycon.org/2010/talks/42-biomedical-text-mining-with-python-some-experiments). You might considering using NLTK instead of rolling your own solution.

Comment: @Vinay: the problem with NLTK is that it's quite slow. (I'm not opposed to it, in fact I contributed to it, but since the OP is asking for optimization, it's not the first thing that comes to mind.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of building one RE per `term`, build a single, disjunctive one that can catch all of them:

```
pattern = re.compile("(%s)" % "|".join(re.escape(term) for term in dictionary))
```

then use `pattern.finditer`.

As for "how to use machine learning", that's far too broad a question, IMHO. Start out by googling for "biomedical named entity recognition" -- there's a vast amount of literature about that problem and assorted tools.

Comment: OK Thanks, today I will probe this way. I replace puntuation marks by spaces in sentences (it is possible 2 or 3 puntuations marks together), then if term is composed of several words my regular expression is '('+"\s*".join(term.split())+')' then with your code, it will be:



`pattern = re.compile("(%s)" % "|".join(re.escape("\s*".join(term.split())) for term in dictionary))`

Comment: @nathan: watch out with `re.escape`, it removes the meaning of `*` etc. so you'll want to apply it inside the `str.join`.

Comment: Then `pattern = re.compile("(%s)" % "|".join(re.escape(term).replace(" ", "\s*") for term in dictionary))`

Comment: In few hours I will write my result!!! Thanks :D
But the problem in this dusjunctive, I can not know wich term is matche to map with its identifier in my dictionary.

Comment: @nathan: `finditer` returns a iterator over match objects. Call `.group(0)` on these.

Comment: My dictionary is really big...

`OverflowError: regular expression code size limit exceeded`

I can try split my dictionary in several patterns.

Comment: @nathan: never heard of that. Use at your own risk :)

Comment: With a subset of terms (~500), my previous algorith takes 1540 seconds, and now, with your proposal 222 seconds!!! I am... WOOOOOO!!! :D
I hope that the new regexp package can improve it more!!! Thanks again @larsmans :)

Comment: I have tried the same algorithm in JAVA, the compilation is faster, but the recognition step takes more than 15 hours... Yes, I am working in Python for recognition, but it will be more usable for me if I use JAVA (the other code is written in JAVA). Could I change my code to adapt it?

Comment: @nathan: well, sure, but I'm not familiar enough with Java to know how to express this efficiently.